# CONFIG_ASYNC_XOR not visible through menuconfig/gconfig

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using linux kernel version 2.6.26.8 and I need to use async_XXX (async_xor, async_memcpy etc) API. So I need to build the ASYNC_XXX modules with my kernel. But I can't see the config options related to ASYNC_XOR or ASYNC_MEMCPY etc through menuconfig or gconfig under Security Options.

In gconfig if I select show all options I can see these config options under "Security Options" but I can't select them.

I am not sure if this is because of some missing prerequisite CONFIG options in my config file or something else.
I could directly add these options in the config file manually but I wanted to be sure it won't have any side effects.

I am posting the Security Options portion of my working .config file here...

#

## Security options

#

## CONFIG_KEYS is not set

## CONFIG_SECURITY is not set

## CONFIG_SECURITY_FILE_CAPABILITIES is not set

CONFIG_CRYPTO=y

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,
Vikash Kumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer is there isn't a menu option to select these items; instead, they need to be selected indirectly via a second option.

Looking at `crypto/async_tx/Kconfig` you can see the various options in question (`ASYNC_XOR`, `ASYNC_MEMCPY`, etc), but none of the tristate options have a prompt string. Without a prompt string, you will not see the option when running something like gconfig or menuconfig.

Take a look at the RAID4/5/6 driver (`drivers/md/Kconfig`) configuration. Selecting this driver indirectly selects `ASYNC_MEMCPY` and `ASYNC_XOR`. If you are developing a driver that needs these options, you should consider selecting these options in the driver's config block. Alternatively, if this is a platform wide feature, you might consider selecting these options in the config block of whichever `arch/*/mach-*/Kconfig` you are building.

Comment: Thanks ctuffli this answers my query perfectly.